# multiple delimeter and want to include that delimeter one of them in string using regex

Tags: java, regex

i wanna ask something, this is my code

```
string.split("\\+|(?=-)|([=-]?=-)|=");
```

my input `2x^2+3x-9=-2`

output :

```
2x^2 3x -9 2
```

my expected output :

```
2x^2 3x -9 -2
```

Comment: You might not be able to get away with `2+-3=-1` either.

Comment: Have you looked into lookahead and lookbehind? You don't want to split on a sign character unless it's preceded by a digit or letter.

Comment: Alternatively, you don't want to split on a sign character preceded by any other special character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `=` alternative before `[=-]?=-`:

```
\+|=|(?=-)|([=-]?=-)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/B7kE9R/1

Comment: 2x^2+3x-9=-2
[2x^2, 3x, -9, , -2] thank you but there are blank space in index of 3, how to remove that with regex code above?